# Gridview not sorting and paging for excel sheet in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sorting, paging

I have a gridview and it is taking the data from an excel sheet. In visual studio, from the properties menu of the gridview I have just set paging and sorting enabled. But this is not working. Is it about the excel source or should I add some extra code ?

```
 string whereClause = SearchTextBox.Text;
        String name = "Sheet0";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "C:\\Users\\BerkayS\\Desktop\\VSCLOGN.xls" +
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";





        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select " + selectedCriteria + " From [" + name + "$] where USER_ID = '" + whereClause + "'", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        GridView2.DataSource = data;
        GridView2.DataBind();


        GridView2.Visible = true;
```

Note: Ignore some variable names in the code, they are assigned before

Comment: If everything is fine while debugging your application (i.e. `data.Rows.Count` corresponding to number of rows in Excel) then you are losing data during `PostBack` event.

Comment: You need extra code for sorting and paging. See [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/663532/how-to-perform-sorting-in-gridview-in-asp-net) to get you started.